# Android Studio won't start on Mac OS Sierra

Tags: android-studio, macos-sierra

I have recently starting encountering an issue where Android Studio will not open on Mac OS Sierra.

The splash screen loads but then disappears, it's almost as though the app is open in the background, i'm not sure what causes this as it worked perfectly before.

I've searched online but no luck as yet, any thoughts?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The issue seems to have been resolved.
I re-opened visual studio a week later and it was able to run successfully.

still not sure what the cause was though.